# Placing a view inside a layout dynamically at a specific position in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a dialog window in Android where I am dynamically creating the layout and adding the views in to it. But I want to add my view to a specific position in layout.

Here is my code snippet

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
FrameLayout fl=new FrameLayout(this);
TextView et = new TextView(this);
et.setText("asdas");

fl.addView(et,100,1200);

ColorDrawable cd=new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(cd);
dialog.setContentView(fl);
```

Comment: specific means? where you want to add?

Comment: @GopalRao the dialog window is full screen... i want to add a text view at a specific position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to place a image button at a specified location in my relative layout. hope this helps:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.leftMargin = (int)(marginLeft);
layoutParams.topMargin = (int)(marginTop);
imageButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

**EDIT:**

You can do this for other layouts that support positioning of child views. This method works even for lower API versions. Atleast it worked on API 10. :)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do this  ...something like this

```
   AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER,  getString(R.string.admob_id));
        LinearLayout control_container =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ad_container);
        control_container.addView(ad);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        ad.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and in your xml file...

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#E9E5E6" >
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ad_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but how i add the view to a specific place/cordinates in a window

Comment: ofcourse am able to add the view in my layout...please see the above code...I need to add the view to a specific place using coordinates or anything else

Comment: @sam where it is adding currently.

Comment: @BharatSharma it is adding currently to a Framelayout which is further added to Dialog window

Answer (score 0):

suppose if you want to add TextView at (200,200) position

try this...

```
    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTop(200);
    textView.setLeft(200);
    frameLayout.addView(textView, textViewWidth, textViewHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        FrameLayout frm_layout = new FrameLayout(this);
        android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.leftMargin = 100;
        params.topMargin = 1200;
        TextView et = new TextView(this);
        et.setText("asdas");
        frm_layout.addView(et, params);
        dialog.setContentView(frm_layout, new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                                           android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```